# MongoDB: mongoimport seems to ignore blank field value in first position of tsv file

Tags: mongodb, import, csv

mongodb version v1.8.0 on Mac 10.6.8.

I'm trying to run a mongoimport on a TSV (tab separated value) file.

For some reason, it's ignoring blank fields even though I'm not using the --ignoreBlanks switch. At least, I think that's what's happening.

You can download my test file here: http://pastebin.com/9XzbDfgP

Here's my mongoimport command:

```
mongoimport --drop --headerline --type tsv -d movies -c performances --file ~/Desktop/100performance.tsv
```

So what happens is it ends up importing the wrong fields into the wrong field names (headers). And it leaves off some of the fields. It's having trouble with blank fields. I populated some of those blank fields and it seemed to do better. That's not a real fix though, obviously.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me now using mongodb/mongoimport v2.0.1.